# R reshape a matrix and join columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

before questioning I tried with cast, dcast, but everything went wrong... anyway, I have a data.frame like this

```
Genes                                               Code
 Apod Tptm      cell attachment cell to cell contact cell polarity
 Apod Serpine1  cell attachment cell to cell contact cell polarity
 Adm Ramp2                                        angiogenesis
 Adm Rdr                                          angiogenesis
```

My idea is to reshape the data.frame using Code column to get Unique Codes as rows and unique Genes (avoinding duplicates)  jointly in each case

```
Code                                                  Genes
cell attachment cell to cell contact cell polarity    Apod TpTm Serpine1
angiogenesis                                          Adm Rpr Ramp2
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The community would love it if you provided your example as easily reproducible chunk'o'code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on how to go about this.

Comment: This is actually "aggregating". The functions you should look into using with your favorite aggregation method are `strsplit` and `paste`.

Comment: Ok, ok the point is to get the unique genes    unique(unlist(strsplit(c(DF[DF$Code=="ANGIOGENEIS","Genes"])," "))), my question is how to combine the reshaping with this

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it, too, in base R.

```
#sample data
test <- data.frame(Genes = c("Apod Tptm", "Apod Serpine1", "Adm Ramp2", "Adm Rdr"),
                   Code = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y"))

> test
#          Genes Code
#1     Apod Tptm    X
#2 Apod Serpine1    X
#3     Adm Ramp2    Y
#4       Adm Rdr    Y


test <- aggregate(Genes ~ Code, data=test, function(x) 
          paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(paste(x, sep=" "), " "))), collapse =" "))  

#result
> test
#  Code              Genes
#1    X Apod Tptm Serpine1
#2    Y      Adm Ramp2 Rdr
```